# Disaggregating list of rasters in R?

Tags: raster, r, resolution

I would like to disaggregate a list of raster files in R. I write the following code but receive an error.

```
# Import libraries
require(raster)

# Setup filelist and naming convention based off infiles
infiles <- list.files("infilepath here", full.names=TRUE)
names <- extension(basename(infiles), '.tif')

# Set output file naming convention
outpath <- "outfilepath here"
outfiles <- file.path(outpath, names)

# Loop function to disaggregate and write files
for (i in 1:length(infiles)) {
  r <- disaggregate(infiles[i], fact = 2, method='')
  writeRaster(r, paste(outfiles[i]), format ='GTiff', overwrite = T)
}
```

The error I receive is this:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘disaggregate’ for signature
>   ‘"character"’

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
infiles <- list.files("infilepath here", full.names=TRUE)
...
  r <- disaggregate(infiles[i], fact = 2, method='')
```

looks like you are trying to disaggregate the *filename*. Try `disaggregate(raster(infiles[i]),[etc])` instead. This reads the file into a raster object to work with.